# How i can force colors in email in iPhone 14

Tags: email, html-email, email-client

The device automatically reverses the colors in the dark mode

I Try set colors in
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)

also I try Inline CSS

It is workin is Samsung devices and iPhone 12 but not workin in iPhone 14 pro max

Comment: CSS in  html email template is limited, you should tests your code on 
  https://www.caniemail.com/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.